# Update caption once a screen session has started

Tags: gnu-screen

If I update my `caption` in `~/.screenrc` and have an existing screen session is there any way to re-parse it without closing all shells and starting a new screen session?

Comment: Give this a try: http://serverfault.com/a/194612/222173

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well. I couldn't do `ctrl+a :source ~/.screenrc` because it couldn't find the file using a relative path. Had to use `source /Users/foobar/.screenrc`. Also like they mentioned it reloaded all of my configured screen windows.